# Put imageView just after textview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting a problem in putting imageview just after textview if textview becomes of two line.
I want to show this(Image just after text,text can be in one line,two line or three lines) [image]

My imageview comes just after  textview if text is short(one line).
But when text becomes longer(two lines) then image goes to next line like this [image]

I know the reason of this problem but don't know how to solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lot of googling, I  found a good solution of my problem

```
TextView textView =new TextView(this);
                SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder( "Here's a smiley how are you " );
                Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.movie_add );
                ssb.setSpan( new ImageSpan( smiley ), ssb.length()-1,  ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );  
                textView.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
```

**With the help of above code, you can add image any where in Textview.**

Answer (score 2):

instead of ImageView try *clickable="true"* and *drawableEnd*

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/navigation_icon"
    android:text="Text"
    android:clickable="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make your xml look like below.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry,I think you are not getting the problem.First you try this , write 1 and half line text and try to put image just after text...and check what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="left"
     android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contentText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium T"
          android:gravity="center"
            android:minLines="2"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contentImage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:src="@drawable/browse_product_thumbnail" />


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

-Preeya

Comment: Sorry,I think you are not getting the problem.First you try this , write 1 and half line text and try to put image just after text... and check what is going on.